# How do I start X-window applications in a specific server?

Tags: ssh, x-windows, x-server

I want to start a x-window application on a server named "server1". First I start X server, then on xterm I do:

```
$ssh -Y server1
```

shell says:

```
The authenticity of host 'server1 (10.11.93.232)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is b6:6d:fe:dd:aa:f6:64:1c:1d:6d:66:61:fb:5b:eb:e1.

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'server1,10.11.93.232' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
user1@server1's password: 
[user1@server1 /users/user1]
```

then I run a sh script to start to x-window:

```
[user1@server1 /opt/app/soft/test]$bin/start.sh -t
Error opening display "servert9:0.0"
```

How can I start this application on server1? I think it directs the x-window application to servert9. I think I have to forward X, could you please help?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
$export DISPLAY='my_pc_ip_address:0.0'

$cd bin

$./start.sh -t
```

Answer (score 1):

Your X11-forwarding is fine. The problem is that your `bin/start.sh` script has a line somewhere that explicitly connects to `servert9:0.0`, ignoring any currently set $DISPLAY value.

Edit the script to honor whatever $DISPLAY is currently set; usually you'll need to remove all `DISPLAY=...` and `export DISPLAY=...` lines. If any programs are given the `-display ...` option, remove it as well.

Comment: I don't have any lines with DISPLAY in start.sh, when I do "echo $display" on xterm it says localhost:13.0

Comment: @alwbtc: It's `echo $DISPLAY` in uppercase, and of course it will show the correct value on xterm -- it's only being overriden by this particular program you try to start.

Comment: But start.sh does not have a DISPLAY line,

Comment: @alwbtc, then grep the entire program directory for `DISPLAY`, `-display`, or `servert9`, until you find anything possibly related.